# set image default if image is broken after lazy load image loading . how i do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I can't set a image default after loaded lazy load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setDefaultImage(img) {
    //set default.
    img.src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/logo.png" onerror="setDefaultImage(this);" data-original="http://pacehold.it/600x450" class="img-responsive lazy" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the function declaration out of the `$` function. When the function in the `$` is not in the context of the window, so the html can't access to it. When you move it out you can access it using `window.setDefaultImage` (Try it in the `console`) so the html.

```js
//function setDefaultImage(img) {
  //set default.
  //img.src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
//}

var errorURL = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

$('[data-original]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      src = $this.attr('data-original');
      
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    $this.attr('src', src);
  }
  img.onerror = function() {
    $this.attr('src', errorURL);
  }
  img.src = src;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Error:
<img data-original="http://pacehold.it/600x450" class="img-responsive lazy" alt=""> <br />
OK:
<img data-original="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" class="img-responsive lazy" alt="">
```

Comment: that's run .. but how set data-original in lazy load to default image

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the final image and what is the "loading" image? Is the `src` image or `data-original`?

Comment: 'data-original ' if this broken show another default image

Comment: Thanx .. that's run